# Problem with SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: magento2, database, error

This happened. Just new installation on an old(worked) database.
Could somebody help me please?

> {"0":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'at_status_default.value' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT
>   DISTINCT  COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS
>   `e`\n INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS
>   `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND
>   cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND
>   cat_index.category_id='2'\n INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price`
>   AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0\n
>   INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON
>   e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND
>   stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1
>   WHERE (((IFNULL(`e`.`entity_id`, 0) IN (SELECT
>   `catalog_category_product`.`product_id` FROM
>   `catalog_category_product` WHERE (category_id IN ('30'))))
>   AND(IFNULL(`e`.`entity_id`, `at_status_default`.`value`) IN ('1', '3',
>   '5', '6', '7', '8', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23',
>   '25', '26', '27', '31', '34', '35', '37', '38', '39', '41', '42',
>   '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54',
>   '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '63', '64', '66', '67',
>   '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78',
>   '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '89', '90',
>   '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '99', '102', '103', '104', '105',
>   '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115',
>   '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '130',
>   '131', '132', '134', '135', '136', '137', '139', '140', '141', '142',
>   '143', '144', '145', '146', '149', '150', '153', '154', '155', '160',
>   '161', '164', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '172', '173',
>   '174', '175', '177', '178', '179', '183', '184', '185', '186', '187',
>   '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197',
>   '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '204', '205', '207', '208', '209',
>   '210', '211', '212', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '221',
>   '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', '232', '233', '234',
>   '235', '236', '239', '240', '241', '243', '244', '245', '246', '254',
>   '255', '256', '257', '258', '259', '261', '263', '264', '265')) )) AND
>   (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)","1":"#0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(93):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)\n#1 ...."}